# Same sentences produces a different vector in XLNet

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I have computed the vectors for two same sentences using [XLNet embedding-as-service](https://github.com/amansrivastava17/embedding-as-service). But the model produces different vector embeddings for both the two same sentences hence the cosine similarity is not 1 and the Euclidean distances also not 0. in case of BERT its works fine.
for example; if

```
vec1 = en.encode(texts=['he is anger'],pooling='reduce_mean')
vec2 = en.encode(texts=['he is anger'],pooling='reduce_mean')
```

the model (XLNet) is saying that these two sentences are dissimilar.

Comment: Did you get to know why did it happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of to the dropout layers in the model. During inference, the dropout layers should be turned off but there is a bug in the library. It is discussed here and apparently still not fixed.

See the discussion here: https://github.com/amansrivastava17/embedding-as-service/issues/45

In the mean time as suggested by @Davide Fiocco, you can use the straightforward approaches from HuggingFace. Either use `forward`, `generate` or `pipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, if you have some flexibility, what about using the vanilla `transformers` library instead?

Results from

```
from transformers import pipeline
embedder = pipeline("feature-extraction", model="xlnet-base-cased")
embedder("he is anger")
```

are deterministic.